# Unsetting a value in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm working on a CloudKit app in Swift. So far, everything works well, I can create, modify, and delete records. However, I cannot unset a property of my record.

I'm trying to unset `completed_date`.

```
record!.setObject(name as CKRecordValue, forKey: "name")
record!.setObject((complete ? 1 : 0) as CKRecordValue, forKey: "complete")
record!.setObject(dateComplete as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "completed_date")
```

The problem is when `dateComplete` is nil, the change doesn't save in iCloud. I've tried using the convenience method `CKDatabase.save` as well as a `CKModifyRecordsOperation`, but neither seem to work. When I inspect the local record from a print statement, the `allKeys` property doesn't include a `completed_date`. The rest of my changes are working fine.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/3003388-setobject

Under `object`, it says

> If you specify nil, CloudKit removes any object that the record associates with the key.

[image: Record]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go back to the previous page where you created variables.

Comment: @ElTomato What page do you mean?

Comment: I guess that's my misunderstanding.  Sorry about that...

Comment: You cannot unset a date. You can use a  default date value to indicate 'no date' for your application